Stop laptop turning on when lid is closed
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on Clevo Laptop
When I shut the lid it suspends.
But regularly turns back on, in my bag, draining the battery and overheating.
The issue seems to be it has a flimsy lid, and when squashed, a keypress is turning waking the laptop up.
I know I can suspend 'wake on key press', but would rather not, as it is useful sometimes,
What I'm looking for is a setting: "don't wake up when lid shut, (never, there's no point, the lid is shut!)"
